# Content ID API to determine video ownership

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

Our company licenses YouTube videos - one of our key goals is to verify video level ownership prior to onboarding new creators to avoid a multi-party claim scenario and/or shared revenue (depending on claim type). We can leverage Manual claiming for insights into current ownership by video, but we are looking for a simpler way to replicate and scale this process by querying an API. Is this possible with the Content ID API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `assetSearch` endpoint to get the existing asset of the video.  Using this Asset ID you would then be able to see if there is an exisiting ownership of another MCN/Content Owner using the Content ID API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/assetSearch/list